# Weblogic from 12.1.3.0 to 14.1.1.0

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, weblogic, ojdbc

We are trying to upgrade weblogic from 12.1.3.0 to 14.1.1.0. We have tried to copy the same domain, but when starting the managed servers, the jdbc connections fails in managed server.

The jdbc connection files under /config/jdbc are not getting picked but the data-source connection fails.

The lib folder in the copied domain had ojdc6.jar. We have tried replacing that with ojdbc8.jar, ojdbc7.jar, ojdbc14.jar. All shows the same error.

Our linux platform is RHEL 8, we are also not able to run reconfig.sh from linux as GUI functionality is blocked in our server

**Error Details:**

```
<Jul 8, 2021 8:55:03,448 PM EEST> <Info> <CONCURRENCY> <BEA-2162600> <Creating ManagedThreadFactory "DefaultManagedThreadFactory" (module="null", application="CP-OCMCPo
ol")>
<Jul 8, 2021 8:55:03,449 PM EEST> <Info> <CONCURRENCY> <BEA-2162610> <Creating ManagedExecutorService "DefaultManagedExecutorService" (module="null", application="CP-OC
MCPool", workmanager="default")>
<Jul 8, 2021 8:55:03,449 PM EEST> <Info> <CONCURRENCY> <BEA-2162611> <Creating ManagedScheduledExecutorService "DefaultManagedScheduledExecutorService" (module="null",
application="CP-OCMCPool", workmanager="default")>
<Jul 8, 2021 8:55:03,454 PM EEST> <Info> <JDBC> <BEA-001177> <Creating data source connection pool named CP-OCMCPool, URL = xxxxxx, Properties = xxxxxx.>
<Jul 8, 2021 8:55:03,469 PM EEST> <Info> <Common> <BEA-000626> <Free resources in pool "CP-OCMCPool" will be tested every "300" seconds.>

<Jul 8, 2021 8:55:05,487 PM EEST> <Info> <JDBC> <BEA-001508> <Destroying data source connection pool CP-OCMCPool.>
<Jul 8, 2021 8:55:05,490 PM EEST> <Error> <Deployer> <BEA-149205> <Failed to initialize the application "CP-OCMCPool" due to error weblogic.application.ModuleException: weblogic.common.resourcepool.ResourceSystemException: Could not create pool connection for datasource 'CP-OCMCPool'. The DBMS driver exception was: null
weblogic.application.ModuleException: weblogic.common.resourcepool.ResourceSystemException: Could not create pool connection for datasource 'CP-OCMCPool'. The DBMS driver exception was: null
        at weblogic.jdbc.module.JDBCModule.prepare(JDBCModule.java:406)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.prepare(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:100)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:192)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:187)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.prepare(ModuleStateDriver.java:37)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow.prepare(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:77)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow.prepare(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:55)
        at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$1.next(BaseDeployment.java:729)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
        at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.prepare(BaseDeployment.java:241)
        at weblogic.application.internal.SingleModuleDeployment.prepare(SingleModuleDeployment.java:52)
        at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.prepare(DeploymentStateChecker.java:158)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.prepare(AppContainerInvoker.java:65)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.SystemResourceDeployment.prepare(SystemResourceDeployment.java:66)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentAdapter$1.doPrepare(DeploymentAdapter.java:41)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentAdapter.prepare(DeploymentAdapter.java:193)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.AppTransition$1.transitionAppInternal(AppTransition.java:32)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.AppTransition.transitionApp(AppTransition.java:138)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments$2.doItem(ConfiguredDeployments.java:741)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.parallel.BucketInvoker.invoke(BucketInvoker.java:153)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.transitionAppsParallel(ConfiguredDeployments.java:749)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.prepare(ConfiguredDeployments.java:363)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.deploy(ConfiguredDeployments.java:232)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentServerService.resume(DeploymentServerService.java:219)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentServerService.start(DeploymentServerService.java:133)
        at weblogic.server.AbstractServerService.postConstruct(AbstractServerService.java:76)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor12.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.ReflectionHelper.invoke(ReflectionHelper.java:1268)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.postConstructMe(ClazzCreator.java:309)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:351)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:463)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:281)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:65)
```

Please find the JDBC.xml file that we are using.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jdbc-data-source xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/jdbc-data-source http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/jdbc-data-source/1.0/jdbc-data-source.xsd" xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/jdbc-data-source" xmlns:sec="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/90/security" xmlns:wls="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/90/security/wls" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <name>CP-OCMCPool</name>
  <internal-properties>
    <property>
      <name>LegacyType</name>
      <value>1</value>
    </property>
  </internal-properties>
  <jdbc-driver-params>
    <url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@XXX:1521:XXX</url>
    <driver-name>net.bull.javamelody.JdbcDriver</driver-name>
    <properties>
      <property>
        <name>user</name>
        <value>XXX</value>
      </property>
    </properties>
    <password-encrypted>XXX<password-encrypted>
  </jdbc-driver-params>
  <jdbc-connection-pool-params>
    <max-capacity>10</max-capacity>
    <capacity-increment>2</capacity-increment>
    <connection-creation-retry-frequency-seconds>600</connection-creation-retry-frequency-seconds>
    <test-frequency-seconds>300</test-frequency-seconds>
    <test-connections-on-reserve>true</test-connections-on-reserve>
    <inactive-connection-timeout-seconds>5400</inactive-connection-timeout-seconds>
    <test-table-name>dual</test-table-name>
    <login-delay-seconds>1</login-delay-seconds>
    <init-sql>SQL alter session set REMOTE_DEPENDENCIES_MODE = SIGNATURE</init-sql>
  </jdbc-connection-pool-params>
</jdbc-data-source>
```

Could you please help us on this issue.

Comment: This isn't on-topic for this site. But why are you specifying `net.bull.javamelody.JdbcDriver` instead of a standard driver; and if you do want to use that, have you made that driver available to the new domain? You only mentioned the `ojdbc.Xjar` files; though you shouldn't need to supply your own copies of those anyway as WebLogic includes drivers.

Comment: I hope you are aware that ojdbc14.jar is for Java 1.4; not something you should be using this day and age.

Comment: The driver name mentioned was in the previous weblogic 12.1.3 version. We have also tried creating data source from admin console, face the same error